# How to resolve './components/AppFooter' or its corresponding type declarations. Error on Netlify and railway.app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, netlify

Hhile deploying I am getting error, it is Vite + React + Typescript app.

```
9:27:22 AM: $ tsc && vite build
9:27:23 AM: src/App.tsx(2,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module './components/AppFooter' or its corresponding type declarations.
9:27:23 AM: src/App.tsx(3,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module './components/AppHeader' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Where I am getting error, appheader and appfooter contains just  printing "working".

```
import "./App.css";
import AppFooter from "./components/AppFooter";
import AppHeader from "./components/AppHeader";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AppHeader></AppHeader>
      <AppFooter></AppFooter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My file structure:

[image: structure]

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vite---react---typescript",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx http-server ./dist",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

I tried changing the casing and changing the file name, it is working perfectly fine on my local but not when I deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your components are in ./components/main, so you will need to update the paths on the imports, e.g.

```
import AppFooter from "./components/main/AppFooter";
```